# A c.e. equivalence relation is computable if each equivalence class is of a fixed finite cardinality with finitely many exceptions

Tags: logic, computability

I've been working on the following quiz:

> Let $E \subseteq \omega \times \omega$ be a c.e. equivalence relation and $n \in \omega$. Suppose all of $E$'s equivalence classes but finitely many classes are of cardinality $n$.  Show that in fact $E$ is computable.

Here are my observations:

1. If no equivalence classes are of cardinality $n$, then one can take finitely many representatives for the equivalence classes (this might be nonuniform, but it doesn't matter).  Then each equivalence class $C$ is computable, since $C$ is c.e. and so is $\omega \setminus C$, which is a finite union of the other equivalence classes, each of which is again c.e.
2. Without loss of generality, one can assume that if an equivalence class is not of cardinality $n$, then it is of cardinality $>n$, or even infinite.
3. If all equivalence classes are of cardinality $n$, then $E$ is computable, since for each $x$ one can effectively determine $x/E$ by enumerating it until having enumerated $n$ elements.

But I have hard time in reconciling the procedures for the two extreme cases.  When one tries to decide if $xEy$, given $x, y$, prima facie it appears impossible to decide if $x$ or $y$ lives in an equivalence class of cardinality $n$ or $\neq n$ within a finite amount of steps.

How can I do that?

Comment: Reminder needed: What is "c.e.?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Computably enumerable

Comment: Is that different from recursively enumerate (r.e.?)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No.  Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory#Name_of_the_subject

Comment: Well, r.e. is far more common nowadays, at least in the US.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, the new terminology was coined in late 90s so it's no wonder it wasn't in use when you went to college.  Also, the adoption of the new terminology totally depends on sociological factors: the new terminology was coined by a mathematical logician at U of Chicago, so, for example, computer scientists might feel less social pressure to say "c.e." than mathematicians at Chicago, who almost always say "c.e.", I'm told.  As a side note, mathematicians around me (in the U.S.) just switch between "r.e." and "c.e." in a random manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true. For a counterexample, fix an enumeration of Turing machines, and define $E$ as
$$ x \mathrel E y \iff (x=y) \lor (T_x\text{ and }T_y\text{ both halt}) $$
This is clearly recursively enumerable, and every equivalence class except one has cardinality $1$.

On the other hand, if $E$ is computable, then we can use it to decide the halting problem: Given some machine $T_x$ simply ask whether $x\mathrel E h$ where $h$ is the index of a machine that is known to halt.

Comment: The problem is true if in addition all equivalence classes are assumed to be finite, so I assume that's a typo in the problem.

Comment: @Noah: Yeah, that would work, and would turn the problem into a variation on the "you don't have to know _which_ program decides it" trick question.